# The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'. but my variable is not 'Object' it is a map

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following code

```
  Stream<List<T>> collectionStream<T>(
      {required String path,
      required T builder(Map<String, dynamic> data, String documentID),
      Query queryBuilder(Query query)?,
      int sort(T lhs, T rhs)?}) {
    Query? query = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(path);
    if (queryBuilder != null) {
      query = queryBuilder(query);
    }
    final Stream<QuerySnapshot> snapshots = query.snapshots();

    return snapshots.map(
      (snapshot) {
        final result = snapshot.docs
            .map((snapshot) {
              final snapid = snapshot.id;
              final snapdata = snapshot.data();
              return builder(
                snapdata,
                snapid,
              );
            })
            .where((value) => value != null)
            .toList();
        if (sort != null) {
          result.sort(sort);
        }
        return result;
      },
    );
  }
```

when I try to assign `snapdata` to the parameter `data` in the function `builder` it throws the following error

```
The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.
```

when I try to print `snapdata.runtimeType` it says `_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>`, that means its a map. so, `snapdata` is not an object, its a map, but I don't know why the compiler is treating is as an object, and I don't know what should I do in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code.

```
Stream<List<T>> collectionStream<T>(
        {required String path,
        required T builder(Map<String, dynamic> data, String documentID),
        Query<Map<String, dynamic>> queryBuilder(Query query)?,
        int sort(T lhs, T rhs)?}) {
      Query<Map<String, dynamic>>? query =
          FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(path);
      if (queryBuilder != null) {
        query = queryBuilder(query);
      }
      final Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshots =
          query.snapshots();
    
      return snapshots.map(
        (snapshot) {
          final result = snapshot.docs
              .map((snapshot) {
                final snapid = snapshot.id;
                final snapdata = snapshot.data();
                return builder(
                  snapdata,
                  snapid,
                );
              })
              .where((value) => value != null)
              .toList();
          if (sort != null) {
            result.sort(sort);
          }
          return result;
        },
      );
    }
```

Comment: Problem solved Thanks!. also I changed `queryBuilder(Query query)` to `queryBuilder(Query<Map<String, dynamic>> query)`